# Need help installing pioneer-based code on intel Mac (Big Sur)

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, nix, macos, build

I'm following the instructions laid out in https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html to setup my intel Mac (Big Sur) dev environment for cohort 3 of the pioneer program and having issues.

I've successfully completed steps 1-8 (in the link above): I have nix installed, rebooted computer and the cloned plutus code.

When I do Step 9, which is

`nix build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.packages.plutus-core.components.library`

I get

`error: experimental Nix feature 'nix-command' is disabled; use '--extra-experimental-features nix-command' to override`

adding the suggested tag seems to build fine so I can get by this step.

But then I can't get step 10 to work.  When I enter

`nix-build -A plutus-playground.client`

it replies with

`error: attribute 'plutus-playground' in selection path 'plutus-playground.client' not found`

I'm new to nix and cabal so don't really know where to start to resolve this.  I see lots of other files named pluts-xxx in the plutus directory, but nothing related named "plutus-playground"

Can someone please tell me what do I need to run or load in order to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In step 7, there should be a 2nd line instructing you clone the plutus-apps.  Change plutus.git to plutus-apps.git in step 7 to clone it, then run the playground nix-build from the top of that second repo.

Comment: thanks, this was it.  This list must have been made before the components (like the playground) was split out from the plutus repo and into plutus-apps repo

Comment: also found that trying to run 

```nix-build -A plutus-pab```

in Step 11 wouldn't work for me in plutus-apps. I had to use 

```nix-build default.nix -A plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-pab```

which I found in plutus-apps/plutus-pab-executables/README.md

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's working. Please also consider opening a pull requests against https://github.com/nstankov-bg/docs.plutus-community.com to fix the community documentation.

Comment: done and will look at the docs repo and what I can contribute/improve